# self tour links to faq, not to the help center

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center, tour

The guided tour at /about, links to /faq with FAQ as the text, not /help. This should updated to be appropriate for the help center.

Comment: Not a bug, it's still new and still under development.

Comment: There's a redirect in place, so any links pointed at /faq will go to /helpcenter. We'll update the text on the button soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button text now reflects the Help Center language, instead of FAQ.